# "Connection reset" when using SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have a REST service and some clients get a "Connection reset" error. But SOAP is stateless, so why doesn't it just simply reconnect and resend the request? It actually sends multiple messages in my use case, but the very first fails, and that is just to get some config data from the server. Is this something I need to configure? Should the client programmatically try to resend the message? Some users tried multiple times with the same result.

It never happened in the last years but now I get some reports of this problem.
The client uses in implementation of `javax.xml.ws.Service`, not just a raw socket. But even though I use JAX I get the low level error. It is wrapped by a `WebServiceException`, but that doesn't really help me fixing this problem.
The clients all use Java 8. It's either Update 66 or Update 74.

I am not able to reproduce the problem myself, I only have log files from users.

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getLimits(Unknown Source)
    at xxxxxxxxxxxxx.SOAPServerAdapter.connect(Unknown Source)
    at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out it was about IPv4 and IPv6. I don't have enough knowledge to give a perfect answer but I can post here what they told me. Maybe this helps other devs/users who have the same problem.

So some clients have unexpected connection resets and it's not about server load as it usually is.

If the ISP of the client tries to get away from IPv4 they will give each user a unique IPv6 address (note that the ISP might do this gradually). They do not really have an IPv4 address per client any more, other than the IPv4 used locally, since most still use something like 192.168.0.0/24 for their LAN.

Instead of classic IPv4 they use some [transaction mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism) (e.g. Dual-Stack Lite). Those clients to not have direct access to the IPv4 internet. So if your server only supports IPv4 then they might experience similar problems you get when they use a proxy. They encapsulate IPv4 packets within IPv6 packets for some parts of the communication. From Wikipedia: "The original IPv4 packet is recovered and NAT is performed upon the IPv4 packet and is routed to the public IPv4 Internet."

I don't really know what's going wrong here. Maybe the NAT runs out of addresses / ports or something like that. Or the process takes too long you the connection is reset by some node that is involved in the communication.

So there are two things to do:

1. Inform the ISP about those problems. They probably will help you trace the exact problem and help their clients so they can use your service. For that you need to know the ISP of the users that have the "connection reset" problem. Send them to https://www.whoismyisp.org/ or similar site.
2. Upgrade to IPv6 as soon as possible. Your server can use both versions of the protocol at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Check the load on your server. Looks like server is closing connections because of load - [exception on web-service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874262/exception-on-web-service-call)

Comment: Wouldn't I see something in `catalina*.log`? There isn't much load. And it would drop on large messages, not on the very first one, which generates nearly no load.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be a problem with "Dual-Stack Lite".